# How to Create Posed Duplicates?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, modifiers

I have a rigged and animated mesh that I want to apply the pose of - for each frame. The desired result is an array-like row of slightly different meshes:

[image: An original mesh in a row with three posed duplicates next to it.]

The left-most snake is the original rigged mesh. It deforms with each keyframe. The three others are duplicates whose Armature modifiers were applied while the frame was on the one that was to correspond with their pose. I then deleted their armatures and redistributed them along the X axis.

For just three duplicates this is not too tedious. But I have 90 frames of animation, so I think this is going to require scripting in order to be practical.

I found [some info about running a script for each frame](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27465/running-a-script-for-each-frame), but I'm not sure what to do next. I don't know much about Python scripting.

Any help appreciated.

**Edit: Never mind! While we're on the topic of duplicates... it turns out this is a duplicate question.** [See the existing question and answer here.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19368/store-each-animation-frame-as-new-object) I'm going to close this.

Comment: Good question though. I actually tried and come up with a script based on operators. Have added that as an answer on the linked question (which duplicates this one).