# Alternative to dupliframes in 2.8?

Tags: bezier-curves, path, instances, dupli-groups

Is there some way how to instance objects along path/curve without deformation? All forums and questions I've found are related to 2.79 and they are all using dupliframes, however there is no such option in 2.8.

I can't believe that such a basic feature is so hard to do or at least so hard to find.

Comment: What version do you have? Because I see dupliframes in v2.8 from november build

Comment: I downloaded it one or two weeks ago. I found solution using animation nodes anyway

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/198523/2952

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is really easy using animation nodes.

[image]

Here is version with orientations set

[image]

Comment: Can you add an explanation on what those nodes are doing?

Comment: I believe it will be way easier to understand if you copy the nodes and play with different values. The first picture will make object follow the path, but depending on what you want to achieve, in my case I wanted to place cones on a road I wanted them to be aligned with the road and also be on top of it. So try to disable few of the nodes and you ll see what will happen then

Answer (score 2):

It is true, **Dupliframes** are gone for **2.8**

> Dupliframes have been removed. This was a hack added before there were
>   more powerful features like the array modifier.

https://developer.blender.org/rBS7400aa7e595063510ce9f29fa1b02ebd3f9296e2

As alternative I can suggest using *Dupliface(verts)* on a *Plane* with *Array modifier* along *Curve*.

Comment: Yea, the thing is I really wanted to make instances, not more real objects, like array modifier does.

Comment: Array is only for a plane, actual dupli-object will be a plane's child. AN's Instancer is also creating real object, replicating ALT-D behaviour.

Comment: Yes I know, but plane is real.

Comment: There are a lot of quirks though, I mean ...first dupliverts are not working with single vert, or at least array modifier doesn't and you cannot hide the original object which sucks. You are still creating real object with array using planes (I know it is a lot less than actual object you want to instance but anyway)...there is really not the best solution to this yet. Animation nodes at least provide great control over everything

Comment: I'll just add that for anyone wanting to commit mesh deformations, creating a new object at each frame position, it can by done [with a python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19405/2952).

Answer (score 0):

You can export the objects in .obj format to version 2.79 where you have the option to duplicate them, do the duplication and export it again at 2.80. If you press Ctrl + Shift + A the duplicates will be real objects (instances) in case exporting as dupliframes did not work in 2.80.

Comment: Hah, there is difference between instance and object. So doing this would create a whole set of objects, not a single instance.

Comment: To transform all objects into real objects, first Shift-Ctrl-A to Make Duplicates Real. All objects are now real objects, but still linked copies. To change this, use U shortcut or Object ‣ Make Single User ‣ Object & Data ‣ All. This I would meant :- )