# dupliframe alternative for 2.8

Tags: workflow, instances

I'm trying to create this image in Blender:

[image: reference image]

My first thought was:

1. rotscale animation
2. adjust the curves in the graph editor (the rotation step is smaller at the outside vs )
3. dupliframe

I see dupliframe got dropped in 2.8 though. Is there an alternative that would work in Blender 2.8?

I've been trying to achieve it with an array modifier using object offset for rotation and scale. This doesn't work though because of the need to vary the rotation step

I've also been trying to adapt [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136665/alternative-to-dupliframes-in-2-8), but so far unsuccessful.

Comment: Is it ok for you if it is a simple modelling approach?

Comment: Sure, whatever works! Just trying to figure out how to make it, as an exercise.

Comment: I'm starting to realize that rotation+scale isn't the right approach anyway.. I've got a shape key setup that gets really close. Still no way to create the duplicates though :/

Comment: But...if an exercise, shouldn't you find it yourself? ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

From this base figure:

[image]

We can place a Bezier curve:

[image]

And add a screw modifier to it (360 degrees with 3 steps):

[image]

And add an empty as pivot point for the modifier, then move it up until triangles are aligned:

[image]

You can play with the curve resolution to vary the amount of triangles.

[image]

To render it after that (did not pay attention to the edit mode above):

Convert the result to a mesh and add a wireframe modifier with a low thickness:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very neat, never would have thought to do it this way! I'm stuck on how to render it though.. all I can see if 1) convert curve to mesh, 2) apply modifier, 3) delete the faces that resulted from the screw modifier.. or am I missing something?

Comment: You can convert to mesh (keep faces) then use a wireframe modifier with a very low thickness.