# Distortion in array curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, distort

[image]

So I used Array + Curve modifier on the silver pole (to a bezier curve)
But as you can see the ones in the corner are distorted badly.
How can I get rid of this deformatiom??

Comment: What result do you expect visually? Big spaces in-between poles? Or tip on the opposite side? ... Cyan planks are OK for you with deformations?

Comment: maybe like this? https://prnt.sc/y67qr1

Comment: One answer to this is to parent the pole to a plane with one face, then set the plane to face instance, then put the curve and array modifier on the plane instead of the pole. My problem with this approach is hiding the plane

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/136670/33589